# How to check for the presence of static text displayed from the network in UI tests in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I am using the UI test APIs introduced in Xcode 7 XCTest. On my screen I have a text that is loaded from the network.

The test fails if I simply check it with `exists` property.

```
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Text from the network"].exists) // fails
```

It does work though if I first send the tap or any other event to the text like this:

```
app.staticTexts["Text from the network"].tap()
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Text from the network"].exists) // works
```

It looks like if I just call `exists` it evaluates it immediately and fails because the text has not been downloaded from the network yet. But I think when I call the `tap()` method it waits for the text to appear.

Is there a better way to check for the presence of a text that is delivered from the network?

Something like (this code will not work):

```
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Text from the network"].eventuallyExists)
```

Comment: I updated my answer for Xcode 7 Beta 4. Since it drastically changes the accepted answer I wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Xcode 7 Beta 4 added native support for asynchronous events. Here's a quick example of how to wait for a `UILabel` to appear.

```
XCUIElement *label = self.app.staticTexts[@"Hello, world!"];
NSPredicate *exists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exists == 1"];

[self expectationForPredicate:exists evaluatedWithObject:label handler:nil];
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler:nil];
```

First create a query to wait for a label with text "Hello, world!" to appear. The predicate matches when the element exists `(element.exists == YES)`. Then pass the predicate in and evaluate it against the label.

If five seconds pass before the expectation is met then the test will fail. You can also attach a handler block in that gets called when the expectation fails or times out.

If you're looking for more information regarding UI Testing in general, check out [UI Testing in Xcode 7](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7).

Answer (score 1):

XCode9 has a method [waitForExistence(timeout: TimeInterval)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence) of `XCUIElement`

```
extension XCUIElement {
    // A method for tap element
    @discardableResult
    func waitAndTap() -> Bool {
        let _ = self.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
        let b = self.exists && self.isHittable
        if (b) {
            self.tap()
        }
        return b
    }
}

// Ex:
if (btnConfig.waitAndTap() == true) {
    // Continue UI automation
} else {
    // `btnConfig` is not exist or not hittable.
}
```

But I encounter another problem, the `element` is exist, but not hittable. So I extend a method to wait an element to be hittable.

```
extension XCTestCase {
    /// Wait for XCUIElement is hittable.
    func waitHittable(element: XCUIElement, timeout: TimeInterval = 30) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isHittable == 1")
        expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
        waitForExpectations(timeout: timeout, handler: nil)
    }
}

// Ex:
// waitHittable(element: btnConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right in understanding you that the target text has already displayed when you're checking it's existing, you can try to use `hittable` property.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
let query = app!.staticTexts["identifier"]
expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: query, handler: nil)
waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
```

It will continuously check for 5 seconds whether that text is displayed or not.

As soon as it will find the text may be in less than 5 seconds, it will execute further code.